# how can use the ENV in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the variable in my env file but it's not working. but when I use the variable manually using the ENV file it will be working. what could be the issue

Here's my code

```
function handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
 emailjs.sendForm(process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID, form.current,process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY)
    .then(function(response) {
      return setMessage(response.status)
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('FAILED...', err);
    });
  }

Here's my ENV file

REACT_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID='service_id'
REACT_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID='template_id'
REACT_APP_EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY="public_key"
```

Answer (score 1):

Things you need to check

1. .env files only take after a reboot in the CLI so you need to `npm start or yarn start` after updating any values
2. Try saving the file .env.development which can be used as each Environment wise
3. Try giving the value like this `REACT_APP_EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY=public_key`

As .env files contains key its best practice not to checkin to the source code so add this to gitignore.

**. gitignore**

```
.env.* //So all .env files are removed from the Git
```

Comment: this is exactly what I did but am getting the service id and template id not found